# How can we prevent popup windows appearing on top of the application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, popup, fullscreen

I have a fullscreen window, and I want to prevent pop up windows that appear at the right bottom corner of my screen. I set the Topmost property to true, but apparently it does not help. I also tried activating the form and giving it the focus once it got deactivated, but that did not help either. What is a way to ignore such windows while the user is engaged with the fullscreen app? I am .NET programming in C#.

Comment: pop-up windows is like the antivirus / outlook / Win updates etc?

Comment: yeah, also MSN and Winamp popups. Pretty much any third-party app popup that ruins the fullscreen mode.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can block everything from taking focus.

Comment: @alex: it's not about blocking something, it's about to be on top... **@worlds-apart89** : I think for MSN and outlook, Microsoft worked that that pop-ups be always on "topper top" :)

Comment: Well, I'd like to try something out, but I dont know what it is. Anything you guys can offer?

Comment: You could try forcing the window as topmost whenever you lose focus of the window (use the `LostFocus()` event of the form).

Comment: don't think that the pop-up takes the focus.

Comment: @serhio you have a point there. Never thought about that. Is there any way of knowing the popup has appeared, then?

Comment: @alex: No idea. I had the same situations in some of mine application, but never really worked on a solution for pop-ups

Comment: If you'd periodically force your app to take back focus, would that basically send the popups behind the form (when you click on a form, you usually hide everything except the fullscreen form you have)? It's incredibly inefficient, but I have no other ideas.

Comment: @alex: as the pop-up does not take the focus, you can focus your application each tick of time, the pop-up don't care...

Comment: If this is a game application, you should look at the ways like game developers make a full screen game window. I made this kind of things 10+ years ago with WindowsSDK and DirectX(don't remember a version) combination, but from that time, I immagine, that things are change a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it, this fails the "what if two programs tried to do this" test:

1. those popups are just normal windows like yours, they also use the same top-most style you are using.
2. if there was a way to always be above other topmost windows they would have used it too rendering it useless (because the authors of the other apps are just as concerned about the user missing their "super important" notifications as you are about them interfering with your full screen app).

You can try and play dirty tricks to force your window to the top of the top-most z-order, but those popups are likely to use the exact same tricks, again making this all useless (and as an extra bonus all those dirty tricks can turn your app into a compatibility nightmare).

Comment: agree 100%. In fact at first I missunderstood the question. You are in the host OS and must not impact on other other application functionality (as much as you can) to respect the users of your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable these balloon notifications using these steps:

1. Click Start, Run and type regedit
2. Navigate to the following subkey:

   **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced**
3. In the right pane, create a **DWORD** value named **EnableBalloonTips**
4. Double-click the new entry, and give it a value of **0**.
5. Quit Registry Editor.
6. *Log off Windows* (this is not very cool...), and then log back on for the changes to take effect.

if you need help in how doing this by program, don't hesitate to ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can block all the popups, windows might not let you do that. But you can try with [SetWindowPos function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) and pass it HWND_TOP parameter. It might work a little better than Topmost = true.

Answer (score 0):

I used a sys tray popup control on my personal project [SvnRadar](http://code.google.com/p/svnradar/) written in WPF.

The control is at the  http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon written by Philipp Sumi.
Very nice.Only thing you will be need to "detach" it from the SysTray screen coordinates and 
make it appear where you wish.
Hope it helps.
Good luck.